Jupyter kernel crashes when calling faiss index search method
I'm encountering an issue where my Jupyter kernel crashes every time I try to call the search method on a faiss index. I've tested this in multiple environments with different Python versions, but the problem persists.
I'm running Jupyter on a Mac with an M1 Pro processor. I suspect that this might be the cause of the issue, but I'm not certain. The specific code snippet that causes the crash is as follows:
import faiss

# Load faiss index
index = faiss.read_index("faiss_index.index")

# Call search method
D, I = index.search(query, k=5)

When executing the index.search line, the Jupyter kernel crashes without any error message or traceback. I've tried running the code in various Python environments, including different Python versions, but the result is the same.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue with faiss on Mac M1 Pro or ARM64 architecture in general? Is there a known compatibility issue, or could there be another underlying cause for this behavior? Any insights or suggestions for troubleshooting would be greatly appreciated.
